# Am I Being Hacked by Redirection?

Tags: redirect, dns, bigcommerce, web-development-server

I don't really know how to explain this, so bare with me. But our Facebook pixel detected traffic from another domain. We only have one domain. We went to see what other domain it could possibly be referencing. It turns out, this other domain was a carbon copy of our site. The only thing that was different was the web address. Does anyone have a clue what is going on? It's as though someone is retargeting our customers to a mirrored website.
We tested the foreign site by placing an order using store credit given to ourselves on the backend of our site. The order went through and instead of showing the order was placed in the US, it said it was placed in Turkey.
This is over my head and I have no clue where to start solving this issue.

Comment: Not really a programming question but yes, your site got 'cloned' and someone is trying to steal your customer's money.  report it (to the host provider) and change your fb pixel - engage with some professional to help you determine next steps (free advice here is worth its weight in sand)

Answer (score 2):

I've actually seen this happen to someone else before. I'm not sure what the motive behind doing something like this is - but if the orders from the cloned store are being paid to your gateway, then the upside is that you're not losing money over it. However, I do believe that the intent is somewhat malicious.

The most logical reason I have been able to come up with is that if your store has high amounts of traffic, is well known, and has a good SEO rating, the people that are cloning your store are trying to "SEO-Hijack" you in a sense. Essentially piggybacking off of your site because of the SEO ratings it already has in order to boost their own and potentially turn it into a separate store/website later.

This isn't necessarily something that can be fixed by BigCommerce since the copy of your store isn't on the platform whatsoever, since they are essentially just piggybacking off of your SEO rating. The best option here would be to do a domain WHOIS lookup for their domain and report it as fraud to their registrar as an attempt to get legal action to be taken or a cease & desist.

Sorry that this is happening to you!

[Here's a helpful explanation that I was able to find](https://www.premiumleads.com/en/blog/seo/hijacking-seo/) and a [helpful blog post on how to prevent it and the steps to take.](https://linksoftwarellc.com/blog/how-to-protect-your-website-from-url-hijacking/)

Answer (score 0):

Oh no, I'm sorry to hear about this! As blurfus suggested above -- Please the BigCommerce Support team to report this as soon as you can. You can find their contact information here: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/#contact

Comment: We've been on the phone with BigCommerce all morning and they essentially told us that it was not their problem.

Comment: @calebthomasg Just tagging you here to make sure you see the answer I added!